# I just need to build a Scattered Graph that looks like this? I have tried with Google Charts but could't figure out the right one

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, charts

Scattered Graph with interval(range) based values

[image]

Comment: Did you try the solution below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Highcharts?

Here is a snippet of what you need.

```js
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Height vs Weight'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Polygon series in Highcharts'
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Height (cm)'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Observations',
            type: 'scatter',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            data: [[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
                [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [166.0, 69.8], [176.2, 66.8], [160.2, 75.2],
                [172.5, 55.2], [170.9, 54.2], [172.9, 62.5], [153.4, 42.0], [160.0, 50.0],
                [147.2, 49.8], [168.2, 49.2], [175.0, 73.2], [157.0, 47.8], [167.6, 68.8],
                [159.5, 50.6], [175.0, 82.5], [166.8, 57.2], [176.5, 87.8], [170.2, 72.8],
                [174.0, 54.5], [173.0, 59.8], [179.9, 67.3], [170.5, 67.8], [160.0, 47.0],
                [154.4, 46.2], [162.0, 55.0], [176.5, 83.0], [160.0, 54.4], [152.0, 45.8],
                [162.1, 53.6], [170.0, 73.2], [160.2, 52.1], [161.3, 67.9], [166.4, 56.6],
                [168.9, 62.3], [163.8, 58.5], [167.6, 54.5], [160.0, 50.2], [161.3, 60.3],
                [167.6, 58.3], [165.1, 56.2], [160.0, 50.2], [170.0, 72.9], [157.5, 59.8],
                [167.6, 61.0], [160.7, 69.1], [163.2, 55.9], [152.4, 46.5], [157.5, 54.3],
                [168.3, 54.8], [180.3, 60.7], [165.5, 60.0], [165.0, 62.0], [164.5, 60.3],
                [156.0, 52.7], [160.0, 74.3], [163.0, 62.0], [165.7, 73.1], [161.0, 80.0],
                [162.0, 54.7], [166.0, 53.2], [174.0, 75.7], [172.7, 61.1], [167.6, 55.7],
                [151.1, 48.7], [164.5, 52.3], [163.5, 50.0], [152.0, 59.3], [169.0, 62.5],
                [164.0, 55.7], [161.2, 54.8], [155.0, 45.9], [170.0, 70.6], [176.2, 67.2],
                [170.0, 69.4], [162.5, 58.2], [170.3, 64.8], [164.1, 71.6], [169.5, 52.8],
                [163.2, 59.8], [154.5, 49.0], [159.8, 50.0], [173.2, 69.2], [170.0, 55.9],
                [161.4, 63.4], [169.0, 58.2], [166.2, 58.6], [159.4, 45.7], [162.5, 52.2],
                [159.0, 48.6], [162.8, 57.8], [159.0, 55.6], [179.8, 66.8], [162.9, 59.4],
                [161.0, 53.6], [151.1, 73.2], [168.2, 53.4], [168.9, 69.0], [173.2, 58.4],
                [171.8, 56.2], [178.0, 70.6], [164.3, 59.8], [163.0, 72.0], [168.5, 65.2],
                [166.8, 56.6], [172.7, 105.2], [163.5, 51.8], [169.4, 63.4], [167.8, 59.0],
                [159.5, 47.6], [167.6, 63.0], [161.2, 55.2], [160.0, 45.0], [163.2, 54.0],
                [162.2, 50.2], [161.3, 60.2], [149.5, 44.8], [157.5, 58.8], [163.2, 56.4],
                [172.7, 62.0], [155.0, 49.2], [156.5, 67.2], [164.0, 53.8], [160.9, 54.4],
                [162.8, 58.0], [167.0, 59.8], [160.0, 54.8], [160.0, 43.2], [168.9, 60.5],
                [158.2, 46.4], [156.0, 64.4], [160.0, 48.8], [167.1, 62.2], [158.0, 55.5],
                [167.6, 57.8], [156.0, 54.6], [162.1, 59.2], [173.4, 52.7], [159.8, 53.2],
                [170.5, 64.5], [159.2, 51.8], [157.5, 56.0], [161.3, 63.6], [162.6, 63.2],
                [160.0, 59.5], [168.9, 56.8], [165.1, 64.1], [162.6, 50.0], [165.1, 72.3],
                [166.4, 55.0], [160.0, 55.9], [152.4, 60.4], [170.2, 69.1], [162.6, 84.5],
                [170.2, 55.9], [158.8, 55.5], [172.7, 69.5], [167.6, 76.4], [162.6, 61.4],
                [167.6, 65.9], [156.2, 58.6], [175.2, 66.8], [172.1, 56.6], [162.6, 58.6],
                [160.0, 55.9], [165.1, 59.1], [182.9, 81.8], [166.4, 70.7], [165.1, 56.8],
                [177.8, 60.0], [165.1, 58.2], [175.3, 72.7], [154.9, 54.1], [158.8, 49.1],
                [172.7, 75.9], [168.9, 55.0], [161.3, 57.3], [167.6, 55.0], [165.1, 65.5],
                [175.3, 65.5], [157.5, 48.6], [163.8, 58.6], [167.6, 63.6], [165.1, 55.2],
                [165.1, 62.7], [168.9, 56.6], [162.6, 53.9], [164.5, 63.2], [176.5, 73.6],
                [168.9, 62.0], [175.3, 63.6], [159.4, 53.2], [160.0, 53.4], [170.2, 55.0],
                [162.6, 70.5], [167.6, 54.5], [162.6, 54.5], [160.7, 55.9], [160.0, 59.0],
                [157.5, 63.6], [162.6, 54.5], [152.4, 47.3], [170.2, 67.7], [165.1, 80.9],
                [172.7, 70.5], [165.1, 60.9], [170.2, 63.6], [170.2, 54.5], [170.2, 59.1],
                [161.3, 70.5], [167.6, 52.7], [167.6, 62.7], [165.1, 86.3], [162.6, 66.4],
                [152.4, 67.3], [168.9, 63.0], [170.2, 73.6], [175.2, 62.3], [175.2, 57.7],
                [160.0, 55.4], [165.1, 104.1], [174.0, 55.5], [170.2, 77.3], [160.0, 80.5],
                [167.6, 64.5], [167.6, 72.3], [167.6, 61.4], [154.9, 58.2], [162.6, 81.8],
                [175.3, 63.6], [171.4, 53.4], [157.5, 54.5], [165.1, 53.6], [160.0, 60.0],
                [174.0, 73.6], [162.6, 61.4], [174.0, 55.5], [162.6, 63.6], [161.3, 60.9],
                [156.2, 60.0], [149.9, 46.8], [169.5, 57.3], [160.0, 64.1], [175.3, 63.6],
                [169.5, 67.3], [160.0, 75.5], [172.7, 68.2], [162.6, 61.4], [157.5, 76.8],
                [176.5, 71.8], [164.4, 55.5], [160.7, 48.6], [174.0, 66.4], [163.8, 67.3]]

        }],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image below is created using a server side charting package called [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com).

[image]

The code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="ChartDirector" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="chart" Namespace="ChartDirector" Assembly="netchartdir" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

//
// Page Load event handler
//
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The number of stage 1, stage 2 and stage 3 dots in each category
    int[] category1 = {5, 0, 0};
    int[] category2 = {2, 5, 0};
    int[] category3 = {2, 2, 3};
    int[][] allCategories = { category1, category2, category3 };

    string[] categoryNames = { "5 - 10", "10 - 30", "30 - 45" };
    string[] yNames = { "Stage 1", "Stage 2", "Stage 3" };

    XYChart c = new XYChart(500, 400);
    c.setPlotArea(75, 30, 400, 300, -1, -1, 0xc0c0c0, Chart.Transparent, 0xc0c0c0);

    c.xAxis().setLabels(categoryNames);
    c.xAxis().setLabelOffset(0.5);
    c.xAxis().setLinearScale(0, 3, Chart.NoValue);
    c.xAxis().setLabelStyle("Arial Bold", 10);
    c.xAxis().setWidth(2);

    c.yAxis().setLabels(yNames);
    c.yAxis().setLinearScale(0, 2, Chart.NoValue);
    c.yAxis().setIndent(true);
    c.yAxis().setLabelStyle("Arial Bold", 10);
    c.yAxis().setWidth(2);

    for (int j = 0; j < allCategories.Length; ++j)
    {
        int[] category = allCategories[j];
        for (int i = 0; i < category.Length; ++i)
        {
            double[] data =  new double[category[i]];
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < data.Length; ++k) data[k] = i;
                c.addScatterLayer(null, data, "", Chart.CircleSymbol, 13, 0x2266cc, 0x2266cc)
                    .setXData(j + 0.75 / data.Length, j + 1 - 0.75 / data.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    WebChartViewer1.Image = c.makeWebImage(Chart.PNG);
}

</script>

<html>
<body>
    <chart:WebChartViewer id="WebChartViewer1" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```